# Find why webpack import scss file

Tags: webpack

I have a large project that uses Webpack.
For reason I'm not sure it import a scss file from a directory in node_modules.
Is there a way to track down why that scss file is been imported?

Sorry for not providing the code but I can't do that for now.

Answer (score 2):

1. Temporarily rename/remove that scss file.
2. Rebuild
3. Check output you may see something like following. Now you know it is `app.js` that refered the css file

[image: Magic]

Comment: I hope for something else but I'll try that :)